# I am unable to get my console results to display in a textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, textbox, console

It seems that this code is missing something. Everything compiles properly however, I am not getting the result I was expecting. Essentially I am taking some stipped code from WMIC and saying if protection status comes back as 0, show "Bitlocker Disabled" in the textbox, if it is 1 show "Bitlocker Enabled" in the textbox. However, no matter what I put, I get "Bitlocker Enabled" regardless of the testing computer's status.

```
                try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2\\Security\\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption",
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume");

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_EncryptableVolume instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("ProtectionStatus: {0}", queryObj["ProtectionStatus"]);

                    bitLockerCheck.Text = queryObj["ProtectionStatus"] == "1" ? "Bitlocker Disabled" : "Bitlocker Enabled";


                    // if ((string)queryObj["ProtectionStatus"] == "0") { bitLockerCheck.Text = "Bitlocker Disabled"; }
                    //else if ((string)queryObj["ProtectionStatus"] == "1") { bitLockerCheck.Text = "Bitlocker Enabled"; }
                    // else { bitLockerCheck.Text = ""; }

                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Restart the program");
            }

            {
```

I have noticed that I do get a warning under the line queryObj["ProtectionStatus"] == 1 
which I show below: 
"Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'"

Comment: What are the result you are expecting. Your bitLockerCheck.Text is overwritten every time and shows the last value from the collection.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out :)

Comment: I left my answer below. I know it can be cleaner but I will do that later. For now, I shall celebrate my victory with a beer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can query the last line and convert to string. Then for the sake of it looking good I hid the first textbox result for admin use only and display the answer in a second textbox with the verbage I would like the user to see.

```
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2\\Security\\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption",
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume");

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_EncryptableVolume instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("ProtectionStatus: {0}", queryObj["ProtectionStatus"]);

                    bitLockerCheckInvis.Text += string.Format("ProtectionStatus: {0}", queryObj["ProtectionStatus"]);

                    //bitLockerCheck.Text = queryObj["ProtectionStatus"] == "1" ? "Bitlocker Disabled" : "Bitlocker Enabled";
                    // if ((string)queryObj["ProtectionStatus"] == "0") { bitLockerCheck.Text = "Bitlocker Disabled"; }
                    //else if ((string)queryObj["ProtectionStatus"] == "1") { bitLockerCheck.Text = "Bitlocker Enabled"; }
                    // else { bitLockerCheck.Text = ""; }

                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Restart the program to check Administrative Settings");
            }

            {

                if (bitLockerCheckInvis.Text == "ProtectionStatus: 1") { bitLockerCheck.Text += "Bitlocker Enabled"; }
                if (bitLockerCheckInvis.Text == "ProtectionStatus: 0") { bitLockerCheck.Text += "Bitlocker Disabled"; }
                if (bitLockerCheckInvis.Text == "ProtectionStatus:  ") { bitLockerCheck.Text += "Bitlocker Not Available"; }
```